# Drush Hangs on wget but wget Works

Tags: drush, proxies

Every drush command I run hangs on wget. However, if I run wget outside of drush, it works just fine. I am behind an http proxy and suspect that's factoring into the problem. I don't understand why wget isn't looking at my http_proxy environment variable when run through drush.

Answer (score 0):

Might this help... http://www.xandermar.com/blog/may-20-2014/using-drush-proxy ?

(sorry, I know this is more of a comment, but I don't have the points!)

If not, have you run the drush commend in verbose mode to get more info?

Comment: I had found another page recommending a .wgetrc file. It didn't seem to solve the problem.

I used --verbose to find out drush is hanging on wget. All I see is it starts wget and then get no more information. I believe if I leave it long enough I get a connection timedout.